# Drag and Drop file and folder uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I have ran into a problem: I need to allow a website visitor to drag and drop files AND folders, and handle the upload. Since it is supposed to be a image upload, I need to differentiate between those two before doing any actual uploading.

Question: How to know if dropped item is a file, or a folder? Using webkitGetAsEntity is almost ideal, but obviously, it does not work on neither IE or Firefox (need support for both of them).

Libraries used: I can use AngularJs, jQuery and simple javascript. Using other libraries is not possible.

Can anyone give me any suggestions here?

Comment: If you want to support folder uploading outside of chrome, you will need to look at a flash or java solution.

Comment: Yeh, I guess I just didn't want to give up.. Thanks anyway :)